# SEQUELIZE: How to use EXTRACT MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Let's say I'm trying to extract `YEAR_MONTH` from the records in the `user` table

I can write:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM u.created_on)
FROM user u;
```

I am struggling to understand how to write a sequelize query that involves more complex MySQL methods.

I know I can use something like:

`sequelize.fn('avg', sequelize.col('User.age')), 'avg_age']`

for simple MySQL methods that take only one parameter.

This has been the closest I can get:

```
[sequelize.fn('extract', ['YEAR', 'FROM'],   
 sequelize.col('User.created_on')), 'created_year_month']
```

Which results in the following SQL:

```
extract('YEAR_MONTH', 'FROM', `User`.`created_on`) AS `created_year_month`
```

as opposed to

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM u.created_on)
FROM user u;
```

I am at a loss as to how I can properly build this query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some more digging and realized the correct solution was to use `sequelize.literal()` to add arbitrary parts to my SQL query.

The solution here is to use

```
sequelize.literal('extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM `User`.`created_on`) AS created_year_month')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tasks = await Task.findAll({
  attributes: ['id',

    [ sequelize.literal('extract(year from "Task"."created_at"::timestamp)'), 'year']

]})
```